# Create unique pointer inside a function

Tags: c++, qt, unique-ptr

Is it possible to declare a unique_ptr inside a class (nullptr), then pass its raw value (with get()) to a function which create the instance it will point to?

I have to run an application with a Qt made interface. Qt needs the Qapplication to start in the same thread in which the UI will be updated. To do so, since I cannot do that into my main because i'm also using QP framework(which has a blocking function similar to the qt exec()), i created a class that contais 2 unique_ptr:

```
//MyClass.h
std::unique_ptr<Qapplication> Core;
std::unique_ptr<MainWindow> UI;
```

then in my code inside the constructor of MyClass i start the thread:

```
std::thread(&MyClass::threadfunc,this, UI.get(), Core.get());
```

the thread is:

```
int MyClass::threadfunc(MainWindow* UI,Qapplication* Core){
   int dummy=0;
   Core = new QApplication(dummy,nullptr);
   UI= new MainWindows();
   UI->show;
   return Core ->exec();
}
```

I need the pointer in MyClass since I need to update the UI, so with the pointer to mainwindows I should be able to call its methods, but since it has to be created after QApplication, i cannot istance it in my class constructor.
Then I decided to create all in the separated thread, and since I can guarantee that the pointer in my class will be destroyed after Qt is stopped, I read that it is possible to declare the pointer as unique ones (I could just use the shared pointer, but I want to understand if it is possible to use unique pointers).
To create unique poiters i need make_unique function, but since i passed the raw pointers I cannot use that. I cannot even pass the pointer since they have to be unique (and I use them in MyClass)

The question is, is there a better solution to implement what i want to obtain? or can I obtain it with the implementation I'm using just by doing something different?

thanks

Comment: Why are you creating new objects in `threadfunc` when you passed them in as parameters?

Comment: `Core = new QApplication(dummy,nullptr);` inside a thread! What are you doing? This code proves you are a beginner, so it will be best if you will not use threads of any kinds for until you will gain some experience.

Comment: You also appear to be using GUI elements from threads other than that on which `main` is executing -- that's not supported.

Comment: @PaulSanders because the pointer is declared but doesnt point to anything. The question was about if it is possible to instantiate the object inside another thread if I share the pointer

Comment: Your code isn't sharing anything.  I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: you are right, probably I wasnt so clear. With "Is it possible to declare a unique_ptr inside a class (nullptr)" I mean just declare it, without assign to it anything. then pass this declaration to a function which make the istance of the object I am looking for (the threadfunc). The point of my question is : is it possible to declare a unique pointer but make it point to something in a thread? I pass the raw pointer with Qapplication.get() because I don't know if i can pass it as unique without lose the control of it from my class (the one in which it is declared) since I need it.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` might be more appropriate if both `threadfunc` and the main thread need to share access to the same object.  You can pass that by value to `threadfunc` and it will then share ownership (i.e. the shared object will be deleted when both `shared_ptr`s go out of scope).

Comment: That is the point. I thought about use it, but I read that if I can guarantee that the unique pointer from my main class doesnt "die", I can just use it in this way. Wasn't sure though. By the way probably the best and clearer way is use the shared_ptr as you suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare a unique_ptr inside a class (nullptr), then pass its raw value (with get()) to a function which create the instance it will point to?

You can, but the way you're going about this (from the limited code snipped you've posted) sounds convoluted. Why does `threadfunc` need to take in raw pointers? Can't it take unique pointers? Seems it can, since you control `MyClass`.

At any rate, maybe something like this will accomplish what you want. We're basically stuffing the raw pointer inside `threadfunc` into the class's unique ptr.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
struct A {
  std::unique_ptr<int> p;
  std::thread t1;
  A() {
    p = nullptr; //happens by default, but explicit for OP
    
  }

  void start()
  {
    //int *rawp_;
    t1 = std::thread(&A::threadfunc, this, p.get());
    //p = std::unique_ptr<int>{rawp_};
  }

  void threadfunc(int* rawp){
    rawp = new int(5);
    p = std::unique_ptr<int>{rawp};
    std::cout << "A::p " << *(p) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sleeping for 5 seconds" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000 * (*rawp)));
  }

  void end()
  {
    t1.join();
  }


};


int main()
{
  A a;
  // std::cout << *(a.p) << std::endl; //--> SEGFAULT
  a.start();      
  a.end();
}
```

Comment: Well this is kinda what I was thinking, but I thought I couldnt use p inside the thread like that. the point I didnt pass it as unique ptr is because I have to move it to the func and so losing the ownership (cannot pass by value and I read is bad practice pass its reference). But I need it in my class to trigger some events.
I'm obvious a newbee since it is my first graphical application, but you seem the only one that tried to understand the question and answer it as you could with the information I gave to you, so thanks

Comment: ah, ok. in that case, consider using a `std::shared_ptr`, since it seems to fit your use case -- i.e., you want to reference count + have multiple owners across class boundaries. Also look at move semantics (`std::move`) to move ownership around, though that may not serve your specific purpose. 

As an aside, if you found the answer helpful, please upvote + accept!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is so messy it is impossible to fix it.

Looks like you are using Qt, so only proper use of `QApplication` looks like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

You do not have need or skill do do anything else with it.
The only exception from this pattern is described in [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#details) when application have no UI mode.

Do no use threads. I know they are fashionable now, and this is a buzz word, but they are very hard to master (muti threading bugs are extremly hard to fix and understand and it is easy to write code which will work on 90% computers and will fail always on 10% of machines), so this feature should be avoided by beginners as long as possible.

First master basics of developing Qt applications without threads of any kind.

Comment: I cannot do that because my main program has another point were it blocks (since im using another framework). But since I have to use QT for the graphical interface, and it blocks too, I need to run it in another thread which communicates with my object in order to update the UI. I read that it has to be done in the main thread, but I also read that it is possible to run it in another thread and it should works fine

Comment: Then edit your question add information about both frameworks, since your question is incorrectly stated. This is classic example of [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I specified -"It needs the Qapplication to start in the same thread in which the UI will be updated. To do so,** since I cannot do that into my main**,"- just because my question wasnt about how to run the qt application but how to pass the pointer in the correct way. the qt part was to give some context in case someone already struggle with the problem of running qt in a second thread and recognized the situation. The question is probably unclear since it caused those problem, i will try to edit it then